# Anylogic SelectOutput5 Custom Distribution

Tags: anylogic

I am creating a conveyor system, where the source produces 3 agents every 325 seconds. I would like each agent to convey to different specific areas but am having problems evenly distributing them using the SelectOutput5 block.

I am new to the software and have limited knowledge of Java. Is there a custom distribution function that forces the first agent to exit from port 1, second exit port 2 and third exit port 3? I would like the function to be capped at 3 and return back to exiting from port 1 when the 4th agent enters, port 2 for 5th agent, etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a variable to track last exit and a function to get the next exit.The image below shows an example.

[image]